# Quantizations in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Perhaps this is not an appropriate question for MO, but having just discovered this site I wanted to ask it.

Is there a rigorous definition as to what "a quantization" of a Hamiltonian dynamical system actually *is*? I have never been satisfied with the answers my physicist friends have told me. The kind of answer I have in mind is something "a right inverse to the map which sends a $\Psi$DO to its principal symbol".

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6200/

Comment: See also Weyl quantization (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_quantization) and geometric quantization (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization).

Comment: For Geometric quantization the first reference is Souriau's book "Structure des Systèmes Dynamiques" for french readers, translated in english "Structure of Dynamical Systems"

http://www.amazon.com/Structure-Dynamical-Systems-Progress-Mathematics/dp/0817636951/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1298069182&sr=1-1

Comment: Except for in certain contexts, the answer is "no" to whether there is a universal rigorous definition: quantization is an art, not a functor (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8606/). Rather, there are lots of special cases --- say, from Poisson manifolds to Hilbert spaces --- where you can make precise statements. There is more to be said, but for your question so far I think it's well-covered by op. cit. and questions/6200/. So I'm voting to close as duplicate for now. If it is closed, please revise and flag for moderator attention if you better distinguish this question from earlier ones.